# Giving a title to sections in CollectionView Swift 3.0?

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, xcode8, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView with 2 section. Each section will be holding two sets of images. I want to give a title to both of the sections. Along with this, I also want the scrolling direction to be horizontal. 
For scrolling, I've used:

```
if let layout = collectionFavourites.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
```

This however, will be scrolling both of the sections simulataneously when user scroll on one of them.

To polulate my data in these 2 section, I've used following code:

```
switch indexPath.section
        {

        case 0:
            gTableFavouriteImagesIndexArray.sort())
            let index = gTableFavouriteImagesIndexArray[indexPath.row]
            let dictImage = gTableImageArray[index]
            lblTitle.text = dictImage["Title"] as! String?
            imgView.image = dictImage["image"] as! UIImage?
        default:
            gCollectionFavouriteImagesIndexArray.sort()
            let index = gCollectionFavouriteImagesIndexArray[indexPath.row]
            let dictImage = gCollectionImageArray[index]
            lblTitle.text = dictImage["Title"] as! String?
            imgView.image = dictImage["image"] as! UIImage?
        }
```

I want the images of one section on upside and downside for the other. But I'm getting all of them as like they all belomng to same section.
Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by having a tableView with 2 section ( One row per section).
Then create a collectionView in both the section that will hold the two sets of images.